# Add image from application to excel cells c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What should I write to see images that coming from database in all rows

I want to see the image in [i,2] row.

Here is my code

```
int i = 2;
foreach (var item in chartProduct)
{
        ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = item.Id;
        ws.Cells[i, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[i, 1].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

      string imagePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $@"\images\product\" + item.ImageUrl;
      FileInfo img = new FileInfo(imagePath);
     ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("img", img);
     pic.SetSize(50,50);

      ws.cells[i,2].value = ??

       ws.Cells[i, 3].Value = item.Material.Code;
        ws.Cells[i, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[i, 3].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

        ws.Cells[i, 4].Value = item.Material.Name;
        ws.Cells[i, 4].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[i, 4].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

        ws.Cells[i, 5].Value = item.Code;
        ws.Cells[i, 5].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[i, 5].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

        ws.Cells[i, 6].Value = item.Name;
        ws.Cells[i, 6].Style.Font.Bold = true;
        ws.Cells[i, 6].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
      i++;
}
```

in this part what should i do ??

```
 string imagePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + $@"\images\product\" + item.ImageUrl;
          FileInfo img = new FileInfo(imagePath);
         ExcelPicture pic = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("img", img);
         pic.SetSize(50,50);

          ws.cells[i,2].value = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution,Hope It helps.

```
      int i = 2;
  foreach (var item in chartProduct)
  {
    ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = item.Id;
    ws.Cells[i, 1].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[i, 1].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
     ws.Column(2).Width = 50;
                ws.Row(i).Height = 50;
 // string imagePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + 
//$@"\images\product\" + item.ImageUrl;
string filePath= "~/images/product/" + item.ImageUrl;
 AddPictures(ws, filePath,i,2);

   ws.Cells[i, 3].Value = item.Material.Code;
    ws.Cells[i, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[i, 3].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

    ws.Cells[i, 4].Value = item.Material.Name;
    ws.Cells[i, 4].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[i, 4].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

    ws.Cells[i, 5].Value = item.Code;
    ws.Cells[i, 5].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[i, 5].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;

    ws.Cells[i, 6].Value = item.Name;
    ws.Cells[i, 6].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[i, 6].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
  i++;
  }
```

separate method to add Picture

```
public void AddPictures(ExcelWorksheet ws, string filePath,int row,int col)
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
        OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture pic =ws.Drawings.AddPicture(string.Format("Pic{0}",row), image);      
        pic.SetPosition(row-1, 0,0,0);
        pic.SetSize(50,50);
    }
```

Comment: i did what you suggested but there is same problem. In excell file the ımage looks at the top left not the under column that i wanted

Comment: Hello @AlkınÇakıralar I have done few changes to the previous code and it is working fine now, I have written the code to fix the image inside the excel cell.